# rate of convergence for cross derivative estimation in local linear regression

Tags: asymptotics, derivative, nonparametric-regression

Suppose $Y_{i}=m(X_{1i},X_{2i})+\epsilon_{i}$, with $E(Y_{i}|X_{1i},X_{2i})=m(X_{1i},X_{2i})$ where $m(\cdot,\cdot)$ is an unknown smooth function. If the estimator $\widehat{m}(x_{1},x_{2})$ is obtained using local linear regression, what is the rate of convergence for $\frac{\partial^2\widehat{m}(x_{1},x_{2})}{\partial x_{1}\partial x_{2}}$? Suppose the same bandwidth $h$ is used for $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, write this rate of convergence in terms of sample size $n$ and bandwidth $h$.